# PrintToPrinter method for crystal reports throws logon exception

Tags: c#, .net, printing, crystal-reports

I am using PrintToPrinter(1,false,1,1) in my website for a crystal report . After I click on this button ( btnPrintToPrinter) it throws LogOnException and says Database Logon failed :

```
protected void btnPrintToPrinter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int empno = Convert.ToInt32(Session["AnyVal"]);

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);



    string strQuery = "SELECT [View_EmplDetail].[Uni-Code], [View_EmplDetail].[FacultyCode], [View_EmplDetail].[EmpIDstr], [View_EmplDetail].[EngGivenName], [View_EmplDetail].[position_eng], [View_EmplDetail].[Emp_no], [View_EmplDetail].[GivenName], [View_EmplDetail].[position_name], [View_EmplDetail].[DariName], [Tbl_Dept].[EName], [View_EmplDetail].[photo] FROM   [MoHEDatabase].[dbo].[View_EmplDetail] [View_EmplDetail] INNER JOIN [MoHEDatabase].[dbo].[Tbl_Dept] [Tbl_Dept] ON [View_EmplDetail].[DepCode]=[Tbl_Dept].[DepCode] WHERE  [Emp_no] = @empno";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery, connection);
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", empno);
    command.Connection = connection;
    command.Connection.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
    string _reportPath = Server.MapPath("..\\Student\\cardFinal.rpt");
    //rpt.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\" + @"\\Student\\CardFinal.rpt");
    rpt.Load(_reportPath);

    rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
    emp_card_report_viewer.ReportSource = rpt;

    string sq = "";

    //{View_OrgStr1.Uni-Code}=0 and {View_OrgStr1.FacultyCode}=119 
    //sq = "{View_StudentAddNew.Student_ID}=" + Session["AnyVal"];
    if (Session["AnyVal"].ToString() != "")
    {
        sq = "{View_EmplDetail.Emp_no}=" + int.Parse(Session["AnyVal"].ToString());
    }

    //emp_card_report.Report.FileName = "../Student/CardFinal.rpt";
    emp_card_report_viewer.SelectionFormula = sq;
    //ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    //connInfo.ServerName = "172.16.0.15";
    //connInfo.DatabaseName = "MoHEMISDatabase";
    //connInfo.UserID = "myuser";
    //connInfo.Password = "myuser@sabir";
    //TableLogOnInfos crtt = new TableLogOnInfos();
    //TableLogOnInfo crtto = new TableLogOnInfo();
    //Tables crtables;
    //crtables = rpt.Database.Tables;
    //foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table crtable in crtables)
    //{
    //    crtto = crtable.LogOnInfo;
    //    crtto.ConnectionInfo = connInfo;
    //    //crtable.ApplyLogInInfo(crtto);
    //}
    ConnectionInfo connInfo1 = new ConnectionInfo();
   // connInfo1.ServerName = "server";

    setDBLOGONforReport(connInfo1);



    //emp_card_report_viewer.RefreshReport();


    //ConnectionInfo connInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    //connInfo.ServerName = "server";
    //connInfo.DatabaseName = "MoHEDatabase";
    //connInfo.UserID = "hemis_admin";
    //connInfo.Password = "hemis@sabir";



    //setDBLOGONforReport(connInfo);


    CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins pageMargins = new
    CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    rpt.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(pageMargins);

    rpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerList.SelectedItem.Value;
    emp_card_report_viewer.RefreshReport();

    rpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, 1);


    rpt.Close();
    rpt = null;
}
```

error appears at : rpt.PrintToPrinter(1,falase,1,1);

any idea where it goes wrong ??? 
I have commented out some of the lines, just was checking on them ...

any help would be appreciated...tnx

Answer (score 2):

Lucky, I suspect you don't mean "after I compile" that it throws the error. I'm assuming you mean "after I click my 'btnPrintToPrinter' button in my web application"? Whatever the case, please update the question to be more specific in how you trigger the error?

If your 'btnPrintToPrinter' button is sitting on the web page the moment you click it you get database logon failed, it is probably because you are doing two things that contradict each other:

1) You first assign a database as the report's datasource.
-THEN-
2) You are setting connection details for the report, i.e.

```
ConnectionInfo connInfo1 = new ConnectionInfo(); 
setDBLOGONforReport(connInfo1);
```

Remove these extra steps where you set connection info. The report doesn't need connection information if you are PUSHING a datatable to it. (Once you feed a report data it isn't going to connect to the server to get the data again.)

Note: IF you still see problems after you remove these lines. The issue is probably that the datatable you are passing is not what the report was build on in the first place. For example:

1) You built the report using a table named 'TableA' with 'field1', 'field2' and 'field3'. 
2) Then you build a datatable in your code by querying 'TableA' with 'field1', 'field2' and 'fieldx' and 'fieldz'.
3) You pass the table from #2 into the report.

This can cause database logon errors (even though it's not really a logon problem). Because the report does this:

1) It TRIES to use the data you passed in. Then it CAN'T because the fields *do not match* what the report was designed from.
2) THEN the report, having no data, attempts to connect to the database server it WAS built on before.
3) Since you haven't (and *should not*) pass valid connection information to the report, it NOW throws 'database logon failed'.

So you see, it isn't really because the logon failed that you have a problem. It's because the data you provided (which makes the report NOT NEED to connect) was invalid data. As I said earlier, even one field being different can make the report fail. In fact, even just changing a single field's type (say varchar to int, or varchar(5) to nvarchar(10), etc.) can make the data you pass NOT match the data the report was built on.

So in your page load event (where I'm assuming you set

Comment: I have updated the post also ... after i click on btnPrintToPrinter... ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have used this:

```
myReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username","password");
```

method and it solved the problem.

Comment: Lucky, if you are using SetDatabaseLogon the report will typically go to the database instead of using the dataset you pass to it. So officially you should know that passing a dataset to a report should eliminate the need to call SetDatabaseLogon.

Comment: ya but If i dont pass the dataset this way after exporting my report to pdf or printing the report no data will appear on pdf/printed document .... and if I dont use SetDatabaseLogon It throws that error .... !!!

Comment: Yes, I understand. If this is the case I bet if you remove "rpt.SetDataSource(dt);" and ALL the code that builds that "dt" datatable, it will STILL work. Try it. :D

Comment: ya :D :D , I bet it works too, but I am filtering data through DataAdapter and only push one row in the DataTable so if I remove all those codes it will start printing the whole list ..... but I only want one record ....

Comment: You are filtering using the viewer though:  emp_card_report_viewer.SelectionFormula = sq; 
Are you positive it doesn't still filter when you remove the dt code? If you are using SetDatabaseLogon I don't think it's even using your datatable. I think it rejects your datatable because it isn't a perfect match of the report's original design. (I mention this in paragraph 3 of my answer.) Then it goes to the server and pulls data and filters based on the filter you pass to the viewer.

Comment: hummm .... to check it I removed rpt.SetDataSource(dt) and compiled it .... the result was " OMG what the hell has happened to my printer..." it was just printing all the records :(